# Seaborn | Matplotlib: Scatter plot: 3rd variable is encoded by both size and colour

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to create a plot that shows the geographical distribution of nightly prices using longitude and lattitude as coordinates, and the price encoded both by color and size of the circles. I curently have no idea on how to encode the plots by the price in both colour and size. I come to you in search of help~ I dont understand the documentation for seaborn in this scenario.

3 columns of interest:

```
longtitude     lattitude     Price

50.1235156     4.1236436     160
52.3697862     4.8935462     300
52.3640489     4.8895343     8000
52.3729765     4.8931707     1300
52.3657530     4.8796741     5000
52.2957663     4.3058365     60
52.6709324     4.6028347     100
```

In my scenario: each column is of equal length, but I only want to include prices that are `>150`

Im stuck with this filter in play, as the column  with the applied filter is half the size as `longitude` and `latitude`.

**My clueless attempt:**

```
plt.scatter(df.longitude, df.latitude, s=(df.price)>150, c= (df.price)>150)
```

The way I understand it is that the latitude and longitude create the space/plane, and then apply the price data. But implementing it seems to work differently?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to filter the dataframe before plotting. If you do what you're doing (which won't work anyway), your Series of x and y coordinates will be the entire length of the dataframe but series responsible for color-coding and size will be shorter because you're trying to filter out values under 150 with this: `s=(df.price)>150`.

Secondly, you can't plot like this using matplotlib. With matplotlib to color-code points you need to create a dictionary, so I'd suggest using seaborn for simplicity.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_plot = df.loc[df.price > 150]

fig = sns.scatterplot(data=df_plot, x='longitude', y='latitude', size='price', hue='price')
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you for your input, although i get the following error
```AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'view'```
asssuming the ```data=df.plot``` is a typo for ```data=df_plot```
Your comments do make much sense, and i understand entirely on the filtering of df.

Comment: @DropKick, yeah, it was a typo, sorry. Can you show the traceback from the error you're getting? I'm not sure where `view` might be coming from.

Comment: ```df2 = df[['longitude', 'latitude', 'price']]

df_Scatter = df2[df2['price']>150]


fig = sns.scatterplot(data=df_Scatter, x='longitude', y='latitude', size = 'price', hue ='price')

plt.show()```

attribute error on scatterplot line